# How to properly connect a Node app to Mysql using docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

First of all, here is my folder structure:

[image]

**db/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**web/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.16.0

# Set the work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install packages
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install

# Add application files
COPY . /app

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=docker
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

**db/script.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `docker` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `docker`;
```

**Node app**

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'db',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'docker'
});
```

Whenever I run `docker-compose up` I always get

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.80.3:3306
web_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
web_1  |     --------------------
web_1  |     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
web_1  |     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
web_1  |     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
web_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:12)
web_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
web_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
web_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
web_1  |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
web_1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
web_1  |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |   address: '192.168.80.3',
web_1  |   port: 3306,
web_1  |   fatal: true }
```

Am I missing something here? I am running it on Windows 10.

Comment: The error `ECONNREFUSED` means that it is not possible to connect to port 3306 on 192.168.80.3.  The most likely reason for this is that the database isn't ready, but you could also add a `ports:` line to the `docker-compose.yml` for db and see if that makes it accessible.  [This question asks about how to make sure X is running before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31746182/103081) and may also be of interest.

Comment: you missed to expose port in DB contaienr

Comment: @Paul Hi. Already tried your suggestion before and got the same output. So likely the reason is that it's not yet ready?

Comment: Either the app configuration and the db service ports have mismatched port numbers, the db port is inaccessible (firewall, etc.), or the app tries to contact the db before the db listens on the port. This is a fairly low level networking issue.  It is not about what is in the database, or having the correct database password.

Comment: I will try and give some updates @Paul. Thank you.